# Почему "расти", если "рост"?

Tags: орфография

Почему пишется "расти", если проверочное слово "рост"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В русском языке есть правило относительно безударных корней "-рос-" и "-раст-". Так, в корнях без Т "-рос-" пишется О, а в корнях с Т "-раст" - А.
Примеры: *расти, рослый, растение*.
Исключения: *росток, Ростов, Ростислав, отрасль*.

Comment: Ещё в корне "-ращ-" тоже будет А

Comment: В слове "рослый" на О падает ударение. По-другому не напишешь.

Answer (score 4):

Рост не проверочное слово! Здесь две орфограммы: расти - корни с чередованием. Рост - проверяемые безударные гласные в корне.

Answer (score 3):

Правило из разряда правописания корней с чередующимися гласными. В корнях с чередующимися гласными *раст-*, *ращ-* и *рос-* пишется гласная «а» перед последующим сочетанием «ст» или «щ». Во всех остальных случаях пишется гласная "о". Исключениями из данного правила являются слова *Ростов* (в том числе фамилия и производные от неё), *ростовщик*, *росток*, *отрасль*, имя Ростислав.

Answer (score 1):

Все безударные гласные корня делятся на проверяемые (проверяем ударением), непроверяемые (запоминаем), чередующиеся (применяем соответствующее правило). Правило передано верно. Список исключений или особых слов можно продолжить: например, слово "подростковый". По правилу - а. По тем же правилам - проверять нельзя. А пишем О. В списках исключений тоже обычно это слово не упоминают.

Answer (score 0):

Это чередование гласных в корне "рос"/"раст". См. справочник Розенталя: "Правописание гласных в корне" -> "[Чередующиеся гласные](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/22.htm#%D0%B7_03)":

> В корне **раст-** – **рос-** пишется а перед последующим сочетанием **ст** (также перед **щ**), в остальных случаях пишется **о**: расти, наращение – выросший, заросль, поросль.
>
> Исключения: отрасль (хотя нет **cm**); росток, выросток, ростовщик, Ростов и др. (хотя есть **cm**).